# How to shorten the line distance in slope plot created by ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am using ggplot to create a plot for ranking comparison.

```
State <- c("Food Insecurity","Health and Sanitation","Community Involvment", "Biodiversity","Authorities Coordination Capacity","Wellbeing","Younger Generations Engagement","Livelihood","Household Diet", "Health and Sanitation","Wellbeing","Food Insecurity","Community Involvment",
"Livelihood","Authorities Coordination Capacity","Biodiversity","Younger Generations Engagement","Household Diet")
Rank <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9)
Method <- c("DCE","DCE","DCE","DCE","DCE","DCE","DCE","DCE","DCE","Likert","Likert","Likert","Likert","Likert","Likert","Likert","Likert","Likert")
data <- data.frame(State, Rank, Method)

state <- ggplot(data = data, aes(x = Method, y = Rank, group = State)) +
  geom_line(aes(color = State, alpha = 1), size = 1.2) +
  geom_text(data = data %>% filter(Method == "DCE"), 
            aes(label = paste0(State, " - ", Rank)) , 
            hjust = 1, 
            fontface = "plain", 
            size = 3) +
  geom_text(data = data %>% filter(Method == "Likert"), 
            aes(label = paste0(Rank, " - ", State)) , 
            hjust = 0, 
            fontface = "plain", 
            size = 3) +
  scale_x_discrete(position = "top")+
  scale_y_reverse() +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(legend.position = "none") +
  theme(panel.border     = element_blank()) +
  theme(axis.title.y     = element_blank()) +
  theme(axis.text.y      = element_blank()) +
  theme(panel.grid.major.y = element_blank()) +
  theme(panel.grid.minor.y = element_blank()) +
  theme(axis.title.x     = element_blank()) +
  theme(panel.grid.major.x = element_blank()) +
  theme(axis.text.x.top      = element_text(size=9,color = "black")) +
  theme(axis.ticks       = element_blank()) +
  theme(plot.title       = element_text(size=9, face = "plain", hjust = 0.5),
        plot.tag = element_text(size=12),
        plot.tag.position = c(0.05,1)) +
  #  Labelling as desired
  labs(
    title = "State",
    tag = "(e)")
state

ggsave("State.jpeg",width = 22, height = 5, units = "cm",dpi=600)
```

The output graph is
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5YQvh.jpg)

I would like to know if it is possible to shorten the line distance between the two comparison groups, so that I can enlarge the figure but also keep all the text inside the graph.

Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 1):

One option:

`scale_x_discrete(position = "top", expand = expansion(mult = 2))+` and tweak the `mult` number. This will change how much padding the plot creates on the sides of the two categories, i.e. how much space is *not* the space between the two comparison groups.

[image]